# create universal function pointer to any type C language

Tags: c

I'd like to ask if it's possible to make function pointer that can be assigned to any function later i have.

```
typedef struct 
{
    char *name ;
    void (*func0)(void) ;
}option;

int test(int i)
{
    return i;
}
```

How to cast either the option parameter or the function so later I'd be able to call the option parameter and use it as a function?
I tried:

`op.func0= test ;` 
or:
  `(int)op.func0= test ;` 
failed.

Comment: Please choose either C or C++, but not both. They're different languages.

Comment: If you include C++ member pointers, there's no single type that can do that. And even then, to make sure that arguments are passed the right way, you will need to cast it to the right function-pointer type, or things will likely go subtly weird.

Comment: OK, I removed the C++ tag from the question.

Comment: i saw that post you say its a duplicate , doesn't help at all im using microsoft visual studio C compiler and i cant match types

Comment: Did you look at the answer to that question? Does using a `void*` not work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C you can store your function as

```
void * (*func)();

func = test;
```

But when you invoke it you have to cast it to the appropriate type

```
int ret = ((int (*)())func)(a);
```

This is not considered safe on arbitrary target architectures. On x86 it should work, but you should avoid those tricks on other architectures.

**Edit:**

If you wish to avoid the typecast warning then make the assignment as

```
func = (void * (*)())test;
```

With this typecast it compiles with `gcc -pedantic`

Comment: "On x86 it should work" -- no, even on x86 a strict compiler should reject a program that does this, and in fact `gcc -Werror` and `clang -Werror` both do.

Comment: @larsmans of cause if you treat all warnings as errors this will be rejected. The warning can be suppressed by another typecast `func = (void * (*)())test;`. For readability reasons I have left that one out.

Comment: Ok that will do the trick for casting but what if i want to call the pointer as the real function ??

Comment: @ЃорѓиАтанасовски The value of a function pointer in x86 is just the memory address of the first instruction. When you call a function your compiler needs to know what kind of arguments it accepts and what it returns (if it does). This information is stored in the C type of the function. You can call something as an arbitrary type `void (*)()` (a.k.a accepts anything, returns nothing), but if your function will look for arguments and/or return something it may confuse the caller.

Comment: @SergeyL.: my mistake, turns out the behavior of this actually *is* defined as long as you cast back to a compatible type. Sorry.

Comment: It is well defined. See the [c faq](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/generic.html) - "It is guaranteed, however, that all function pointers can be interconverted, as long as they are converted back to an appropriate type before calling."

Answer (score 1):

It is okay to cast your function to a different function pointer type, you just have to make sure to cast it back before using it.  Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char *name ;
    void (*func0)(void) ;
} option;

int test(int i)
{
    return i;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    option a;
    int i;

    a.func0 = (void(*)(void))test;
    i = ((int(*)(int))a.func0)(5);
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs `5`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited (i.e., practical) limit on the call signatures you may *likely be a able to* use union of pointers of different signatures:

```
typedef union call_sigs_union
{
    void     *void_void;             // pure void pointer
    int     (*int_sig_void)(void);   // returns integer with no arguments
    int     (*int_sig_int)(int);     // returns integer with single int arg
  . . .
} sigs_t;
```

The advantage of this is you better warnings out of the compiler if you are doing something wrong than if you cast everything.

Caveat: this is not guaranteed across many architectures as, in theory, different return types, and perhaps signatures, can have different pointer types. While I have read about a few systems this actually happens on I have not heard about the major players in popular use having such behavior.  Intel X86, Itanimum, Sun SPARC, and IBM RISC are some of the well-behaved systems I have used. Noting I have read on the ARM architecture leads me to believe these would be trouble.

The odd behavior is usually limited to special-purpose processors. Can anyone refresh my memory on systems that this would break on?